# How do I add Send permission to my IoT Hub connection string?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I'm creating an Azure Function that needs to send messages to an Azure IoT Hub. When the function attempts to do the send, I get the following error:

```
2018-04-12T20:19:28.567 [Error] Microsoft.ServiceBus: Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://iothub-ns-monitorhub-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/monitorhub'. TrackingId:a79b2055d85446bd9739bd229aada0d7_G1, SystemTracker:gateway5
```

So it appears I need to add a Send claim to my hub connection string. However, when I go to my hub's namespace and click on Shared access policies, I see this:

[image]

The list of Permissions do not include a 'Send' permission. How do I go about adding a Send permission to my hub's connection string?

The following is the Azure Function where the error is occurring. The code compiles without error but generates a run time error.

```
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"

using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(EventData eventData, out string outputEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    // Get some system properties from the SystemProperties dictionary
    var deviceId = eventData.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"].ToString();
    var messageSource = eventData.SystemProperties["iothub-message-source"].ToString();
    var enqueuedTime = eventData.SystemProperties["iothub-enqueuedtime"].ToString();
    var sequenceNumber = eventData.SystemProperties["SequenceNumber"].ToString();
    var offset = eventData.SystemProperties["Offset"].ToString();

    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
    var message = string.Format("Message Source: {0}; Enqueued Time: {1}; Sequence Number: {2}; Offset: {3}; DeviceId: {4}; Data: {5}", messageSource, enqueuedTime, sequenceNumber, offset, deviceId, data);

    outputEventHubMessage = message;

    log.Info($"{message}");
}
```

Comment: Without any code it’s hard to say what’s going on. Please consider editing your question to add the code snippet that is sending the message?

Comment: @pierreca-MSFT - I have done so. Thank you for your assitance.

Comment: I’m sorry I’m not completely sure about which endpoint you’re trying to send data to: is it to a separate event hubs (in that case you probably need to use this EH connection string) or back into IoT hub (and in that case are you trying to send to the D2C or C2D endpoint? I’m not sure the azure function output binding supports that)

Comment: @pierreca-MSFT - I am attempting to send this to a different Iot Hub. You said, "this EH connection string". What are you referring to? And, thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok I see I’m not sure the azure functions event hubs output binding allows to send data to an IoT Hub but you could achieve that using the SDK within the function code. Which endpoint of the IoT hub are you trying to send the data to? (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints for a primer on IoT hub endpoints).

Comment: Ok. I know I can do this in C# using the SDK because I currently have this running as a web job. I thought I would try to see if I could get an Azure function working. You said that an Azure function probably cannot send messages like this is an IoT hub. I assume it would work if I used a non-IoT event hub?

Comment: Yes it would work if you send it to a regular event hubs. While IoT hub uses some « event hubs compatible endpoints » to read telemetry events, it is not meant to be used like a regular event hubs so I’m not sure it can be used the way you want.

Comment: @pierreca-MSFT. Good to know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated code and comments and got that you want to send events to azure iot hub built in Event Hub-compatible endpoint. But it can be only used to receive D2C messages.

> IoT Hub exposes the messages/events built-in endpoint for your back-end services to read the device-to-cloud messages received by your hub. This endpoint is Event Hub-compatible, which enables you to use any of the mechanisms the Event Hubs service supports for reading messages.

Reference ["Read device-to-cloud messages from the built-in endpoint"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin).

Azure Function is commonly triggered by device messages from azure iot hub and can route these messages to Azure storage or take other actions.

If you still want to send D2C messages from azure function or have any other concern, feel free let me know.

Some references:

[Processing data from IoT Hub with Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/functions-js-iot-hub-processing/)

[Send device-to-cloud messages to IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c)

[Send simulated telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-dotnet#send-simulated-telemetry)

Comment: Rita - You can see from my screen shot that 'iothubowner' already has DeviceConnect permission.